# Mavenized Mule project but Munit test run is failing

Tags: maven, mule, munit

I have an existing Mule project (which has MUnit's also) and now we are trying to mavenize this project. I have used Anypoint studio only to mavenize and project building is success and I am able to get target/test-classes and target/classes folder but when I am trying to run Munit test (tried to run specific test case also) that time it is failing with below error.

```
[WARNING] Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 49; columnNumber: 73; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mu
le/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the do
cument is not <xsd:schema>.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.document.MunitDocumentLoader.loadDocument(MunitDocumentLoader.java:52)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.
java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:171
)
        at org.mule.config.spring.MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:56)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.jav
a:144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:
100)
        at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.handleSpringElements(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:
180)
        at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.reader.MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:41)
        at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.reader.MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:82)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:180
)
        at org.mule.config.spring.MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:56)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.jav
a:144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:
100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.MunitApplicationContext.communicateMuleContextToParsers(MunitApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.MunitApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MunitApplicationContext.java:96)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129
)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108)
        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104)
        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172)
        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95)
        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
        at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89)
        at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222)
        at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81)
        at org.mule.munit.runner.MunitMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(MunitMuleContextFactory.java:85)
        at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.createMule(MuleContextManager.java:97)
        at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.startMule(MuleContextManager.java:56)
        at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.MunitSuiteRunner.<init>(MunitSuiteRunner.java:42)
        at org.mule.MUnitMojo.buildRunnerFor(MUnitMojo.java:311)
        at org.mule.MUnitMojo.doExecute(MUnitMojo.java:173)
        at org.mule.MUnitMojo.execute(MUnitMojo.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Munit test run works perfectly when executing in Anypoint studio but fails when executing using maven command.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.1.0:test (test) on project MuleFlowProject: Execution test of goal com.mulesoft.
    nit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.1.0:test failed: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions
    rom URL location [classpath:processFile.xml]
    [ERROR] Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Learning/CodeBase/MuleFlowProject/target/test-classes/processFile-test-suite.xml]; nested exception is org.spr
    gframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 107 in XML document from class path resource [processFile.xml] is invalid; n
    ted exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 107; columnNumber: 89; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with e
    ment 'db:select'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-proce
    or, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message
    rocessor}' is expected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
```

I googled it and found related issue logged in Mule Jira which is stating that it has been solved in version 3.5

Reference : https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7338

I am using Mule server 3.7.3 EE and Maven version is 3.3.9

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: have you configured EE repository settings in Maven settings file?

Comment: Yes, following repository is already configured https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/

Comment: Credentials also placed in maven setting.xml

Comment: From logs I can see that there is issue with db dependency or namespace name. Is your project build by skipping tests?

Comment: yes, I used -DskipTests=true and I got build successful.

Comment: Which db you are using in your configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem after modifying schemaLocation in mule configuration xml from http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd to http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/3.7/mule-db.xsd

Thanks to @anupambhusari for giving me hint that issue with namespace.

Comment: update data weave dependency for your next issue.<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
   <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>${mule.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

Comment: Thanks @anupambhusari ..I resolved it by importing dw.xsd but then I started getting errors for 'namespace handler not available' for data weave then I used dependency provided by you which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-tracking-ee</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```