# MUnit tests cause maven build to fail

Tags: maven, anypoint-studio, munit

I have a Maven-ized Anypoint Studio project that fails a Maven build upon executing `mvn clean package`; however, running `mvn clean package -DskipMunitTests`results in a successful build.

Stack Trace:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.443 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-09T09:03:52-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/494M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test (test) on project template: Execution test of goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test failed: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:template.xml]
[ERROR] Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Projects/ERP/Integrations/Workflows/Workflows-Dev/template/target/test-classes/template-test-suite.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [template.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException): scala.Option
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test (test) on project template: Execution test of goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test failed: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:template.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Projects/ERP/Integrations/Workflows/Workflows-Dev/template/target/test-classes/template-test-suite.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [template.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution test of goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test failed: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:template.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Projects/ERP/Integrations/Workflows/Workflows-Dev/template/target/test-classes/template-test-suite.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [template.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:template.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Projects/ERP/Integrations/Workflows/Workflows-Dev/template/target/test-classes/template-test-suite.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [template.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.MunitSuiteRunner.<init>(MunitSuiteRunner.java:44)
    at org.mule.MUnitMojo.buildRunnerFor(MUnitMojo.java:323)
    at org.mule.MUnitMojo.doExecute(MUnitMojo.java:180)
    at org.mule.MUnitMojo.execute(MUnitMojo.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:template.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Projects/ERP/Integrations/Workflows/Workflows-Dev/template/target/test-classes/template-test-suite.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [template.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.MunitMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(MunitMuleContextFactory.java:86)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.createMule(MuleContextManager.java:114)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.startMule(MuleContextManager.java:67)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.MunitSuiteRunner.<init>(MunitSuiteRunner.java:38)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:template.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Projects/ERP/Integrations/Workflows/Workflows-Dev/template/target/test-classes/template-test-suite.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [template.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:112)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:template.xml]
Offending resource: URL [file:/C:/Projects/ERP/Integrations/Workflows/Workflows-Dev/template/target/test-classes/template-test-suite.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [template.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:235)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:171)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:56)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.handleSpringElements(MuleHierarchicalBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:180)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.reader.MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:41)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.reader.MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:180)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:56)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.MunitApplicationContext.communicateMuleContextToParsers(MunitApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.MunitApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MunitApplicationContext.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [template.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:229)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:140)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.reader.MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:45)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.reader.MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:82)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.spring.config.reader.MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(MunitBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:180)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:56)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler.init(WeaveNamespaceHandler.scala:22)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:131)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Option
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 78 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.savers</groupId>
    <artifactId>template</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.16</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule Template Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <mule.version>3.8.1</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
        <munit.version>1.2.1</munit.version>
        <mule.munit.support.version>3.8.1</mule.munit.support.version>
        <maven.install.plugin.version>2.3.1</maven.install.plugin.version>
        <mule-maven-plugin.version>2.1.2</mule-maven-plugin.version>
        <mule-mmc-rest-plugin.version>1.2.0</mule-mmc-rest-plugin.version>
        <cglib.version>3.2.2</cglib.version>
        <sqljdbc4.version>4.0</sqljdbc4.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.savers.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>savers-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.4</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.install.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>false</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <muleDistribution>
                        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.distributions</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-ee-distribution-standalone</artifactId>
                        <version>${mule.version}</version>
                        <type>tar.gz</type>
                    </muleDistribution>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${munit.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dynamicPorts>
                        <dynamicPort>a.dynamic.port</dynamicPort>
                    </dynamicPorts>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.nicholasastuart</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-mmc-rest-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule-mmc-rest-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mule-deploy</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <username>${mmc.user}</username>
                            <password>${mmc.password}</password>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <serverGroup>${mmc.serverGroup}</serverGroup>
                            <muleApiUrl>${mmc.url}</muleApiUrl>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/munit</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>${sqljdbc4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-munit-support</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.munit.support.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>Savers</name>
            <url>some url here</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshots</name>
            <url>some url here</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>    
</project>
```

Imports:

```
<munit:config name="munit" doc:name="MUnit configuration" mock-connectors="false" mock-inbounds="false"/>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:template.xml"/>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:global.xml"/>
</spring:beans>
```

I do have `.properties` files in the src/main/app and src/main/resources folders that I have tried importing as well but have had no success.

I should mention that the Munit tests do run successfully within Anypoint Studio.

I have been wrestling with this for a couple days and just cannot seem to spot the issue.

This question [Mavenized Mule project but Munit test run is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773833/mavenized-mule-project-but-munit-test-run-is-failing) is super close to mine, but still not quite what I need.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi zachcdr, Were you able to solve this? I have the same issue, let me know if you can help?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue, too, albeit with my test suite. MUnit tests would pass in Studio, but not with `mvn clean test`. I also already had `mule-plugin-weave` in my dependencies list in `pom.xml`.

I took the advice of Diego in the Mulesoft forums (https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/52086/problem-with-dependency-381-munit-and-dataweave.html#comment-52089) to delete the local Dataweave dependency (`.m2/repository/com/mulesoft/weave`) and rerun `mvn clean test`. It downloaded everything fresh and now works for me both in Studio and on the command line.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because; there is a issue with data weave dependency in munit.
Just drag and drop the dataweave component in your project flow and save it. It will add the dependency in POM file. then you can delete the dataweave.
 Build your project after that.

Comment: A Transform Message connector (weave) just adds:
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>`
to the POM file, which I already have